# User macros in Zabbix trapper name & key

Tags: templates, macros, zabbix

I can't add user custom macros in templated zabbix trappers' name & key, getting this error:

```
Invalid key "nginx_50x_error-{$MACROS}" for item "Nginx: nginx 50x errors on {$MACROS}" on "Template_app_nginx": incorrect syntax near "{$MACROS}".
```

How can I use custom host-macros in templated zabbix trappers? Tnx.

Comment: any glue or some usefull link?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location

Macro is not allowed in the item key; that's the reason of "invalid key" error:

```
nginx_50x_error-{$MACROS}
```

Fortunately, macro is allowed in the item key parameters (Item key parameters - column 7) - and this will be your solution:

```
nginx_50x_error[{$MACROS}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use user macro in zabbix key like this:

key_name[{$MACRO1}, {MACRO2}]
NOTE: Define macros first and then use above logic

Your user parameter file will look like this:
UserParameter=key_name[*],/path/to/executable "$1" "$2"